# What does "out of impulse" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

> After kissing her out of impulse, then I sniffed her.

I checked it in dictionary but I really did not find. 
Sorry if it looks immoral. Actually I changed it but it still looks bad.  The original text actually had a fetish content. Really sorry.

This is actual context:

> I took another whiff, longer this time. Ahh how great it smelled. Out of impulse, I then sniffed the outside parts of the boots, they too were very good.

Comment: You could have answered this question yourself if you had googled for one minute.

Answer (score 1):

It is in the same province with the expressions "out of anger", "out of jealousy", "out of fear." It means to do something without forethought, when you have a sudden strong wish to do something.